# Fastest way to use constant variables in class member function?

Tags: javascript

I wonder which is the most performant way to use the constant variable between the three options below.

```
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 3;

class Test {
    constructor(){
      this.a = 1;
      this.b = 2;
      this.c = 3;
    }
    optionA() {
      return a + b + c;
    }
    optionB() {
      return this.a + this.b + this.c;
    }
    optionC() {
      const _a = 1;
      const _b = 2;
      const _c = 3;
      return _a + _b + _c;
    }
}
```

I know the difference would be small but what if one of the functions is used in a large "for" loop? Would the local variable assignment in the `optionC()` take longer time than accessing the member or global variable? Does Javascript internally optimize if I use `const` instead of `let`?

Comment: Dunno, dunno, no. JS does not optimize anything, implementations do. The answer may vary depending on the engine. Whatsoever, why do you care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from reading your code, optionA seems to be the most efficient. But let's test that theory using the console.

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 3;

class Test {
    constructor(){
      this.a = 1;
      this.b = 2;
      this.c = 3;
    }
    optionA() {
      return a + b + c;
    }
    optionB() {
      return this.a + this.b + this.c;
    }
    optionC() {
      const _a = 1;
      const _b = 2;
      const _c = 3;
      return _a + _b + _c;
    }
}

const lala = new Test();

console.log('Running each option once.');
console.time('a');lala.optionA();console.timeEnd('a');
console.time('b');lala.optionB();console.timeEnd('b');
console.time('c');lala.optionC();console.timeEnd('c');
console.log('---------------------------------');
console.log('Running each option 10,000 times.');
console.time('a');
for (let a = 0; a < 10000; a++) { lala.optionA(); }
console.timeEnd('a');
console.time('b');
for (let b = 0; b < 10000; b++) { lala.optionB(); }
console.timeEnd('b');
console.time('c');
for (let c = 0; c < 10000; c++) { lala.optionC(); }
console.timeEnd('c');
console.log('---------------------------------')
```

This is obviously not very accurate (as options A and C nullify the need for a Class in the first place...) but it gives you some insight.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer with the benchmark. Based on your benchmark, it seems like option C is the fastest while A is the slowest although I don't understand why.

Comment: A is slowest because you're using a class method to return values outside of its inner scope, while C is faster than B because it's quicker to return a value that was just declared on the fly than it is to return values from the Class's constructor.

Comment: "const lala"? Are you sure this is a formal benchmark?

Comment: @StephenDuffy   you're right, I should've said `const superFormalBenchmarkVariableNameSoItLooksLegit`. Thanks, bro, needed a laugh.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly abstract question but methinks...

Option A would be fastest but only because theres an extra few characters to download at "http get website".

Option B resolves to the same meaning as Option A by the interpreter but theres some work involved in 1)resolving the "this." part and 2) resolving that the variable without a .this is a class variable rather than an auto in the method scope. It could go either way depending how the interpreters built.

With Option C, If you instantiate alot of Test objects then option C means your pushing around alot bytes you dont need to. (Well 3*sizeof(const) per object).

Id go for Option D myself because you'll notice with Option D that absolutely no processor work is involved whatsoever.

Good question though.